# this.setState is not a function setInterval react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am trying to write a little snake game and having troubles with changing direction of the snake. I have included the whole component below.

I am seeing the following error:

`this.setState is not a function`

This is being caused in the `changeDirection` method.

See full code below:

```
export default class Example extends Component {

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      snakeLeftPos: 0,
      snakeDirection: 'right',
      boardWidth: 20,
      boardHeight: 20
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   document.onkeydown = this.changeDirection;
   setInterval(() => {
      this.moveSnake();
   }, 1000);
 }

 moveSnake() {
    const { boardWidth, snakeDirection} = this.state;

    if(snakeDirection === 'right') {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
         return snakeDirection: prevState.snakeDirection + 20
      });
    }

    //same logic for other directions
  }

  changeDirection(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
       case 37:
       this.setState(() => {
         return {
           snakeDirection: 'left'
         }
       });
       break;

       //other switch cases omitted for right, up, down
    }
  }

  render() {

    const { snakeLeftPos, boardHeight, boardWidth } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <Snake snakeLeftPos={snakeLeftPos} />
        <Board boardHeight={boardHeight} boardWidth={boardWidth}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

this is not bond to class functions, you have to do it manually in the constructor,

try this :

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      snakeLeftPos: 0,
      snakeDirection: 'right',
      boardWidth: 20,
      boardHeight: 20
    };
    this.moveSnake = this.moveSnake.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: ah yes , makes complete sense! thanks! It should actually be `changeDirection` that is bound to the class though, so you should update the answer

Comment: @peterflanagan i find that it's more concise to use arrow functions which auto-bind to the `class` instead of binding each handler (sometimes when you got a bunch of handlers to bind it gets tedious and add extra bunch of lines to your code)